# Where is the entrance of neo4j's source code？

Tags: neo4j

I want to write a query test and debug it on neo4j's source code(From github), so I have to find the entrance...But where is it? Can anyone help me?(I want to run it on IDEA...)

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j is a server and cannot be used in that way.

Perhaps [this page](https://neo4j.com/developer/get-started/) will be helpful in getting started.